# What is the genre of Jazz that is brass ensemble based, but has more contemporary drums and bass than Big Band and Duke Ellington material?

Tags: identify-this-genre, jazz

What is the name of the subgenre of Jazz that is fully brass ensemble driven - just like Big Band/Duke Ellington stuff - but has electric bass instead of standup, and more driving drums and percussion, with beats and bass lines closer to rock and latin than the shuffle and swing you hear in 50s big band?

The only place I seem to hear this is in 60s and 70s action movie and TV show sound tracks (e.g. Mission Impossible theme), but I'd love to listen to some straight up Jazz albums with the same sound and feel. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a genre name for this kind of music, "contemporary big band with rock and latin influences" probably comes as close as anything. Bands like those of Woody Herman, Buddy Rich and Stan Kenton started the trend in the early seventies. Saxophonist Bob Mintzer's Big Band continued the trend. Some of those movie/TV composers also had their own bands (e.g. Quincy Jones). One particularly good modern example is pianist/composer Gordon Goodwin's ["Big Phat Band"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Goodwin%27s_Big_Phat_Band) but there are plenty of others e.g. Peter Herbolzheimer's "Rhythm Combination and Brass".